# How to Send Message To Solace MQ From ASP.Net Web Application

Tags: asp.net, solace, solace-mq

I am new to Solace MQ. My Question is,

How I can send request to Solace MQ  from asp.net web application. What are the steps I need to performe to achieve this.

I have gone through the solace MQ Dev community and developer guide but it's not too clear for me. I want to understand the basic concept to send request to Solace MQ.

Answer (score 1):

There's a step by step guide, with a sample application to send/receive a message over at http://dev.solacesystems.com/get-started/dotnet-tutorials/publish-subscribe_dotnet/

To summarize it, you will need to create and IContext, followed by an ISession. Then, use the ISession to send an IMessage.

Contexts act as containers in which Sessions are created and Session-related events can be handled. Sessions create a single connection to the Solace Appliance, and can be used for publishing.

Details on the Solace API concepts can be found at
http://dev.solacesystems.com/docs/core-concepts/